# Reading registers in C always gives 0 after the first read

Tags: c, x86, x86-64

If I have the following code then the second register read will always be 0.

So an example output would be:

Frame pointer 1560061208

Stack pointer 0

Character at location 1560061159

and if I swap the calls to rbp and rsp then the second one always outputs 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    void *bp asm("rbp");
    printf("Frame pointer %u\n", bp);

    void *sp asm("rsp");
    printf("Stack pointer %u\n", sp);

    char c = 'A';
    printf("Character at location %u\n", &c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you printing a pointer with `%u`?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`  then use the `gdb` debugger to run your program step by step.

Comment: [The *only* supported use of `type variable asm("regname");` is to control inputs to Extended-`asm` statements](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html).  So your code has Undefined Behaviour in GNU C, and you shouldn't expect meaningful results from it.  It's probably printing whatever garbage was left in `rsi` to printf, and not actually RSP or RBP.   And local register variables don't work for `rsp` anyway.  You can use inline asm to copy `%rsp` to another register, and there are some GNU C builtin functions to get rsp I think.

Comment: @PeterCordes This seems to be a valuable answer! You should totally post it!

Comment: @anatolyg: I noticed that, too :P  Was half way through typing it.  (But it turns out that wasn't the real answer.  The OP forgot the `register` keyword so the `asm("rsp")` was doing nothing!  TL:DR **always check for compiler warnings, especially when doing weird stuff**.

Answer (score 3):

[The *only* supported use of `type variable asm("regname");` is to control inputs to Extended-`asm` statements](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html).  So your code has Undefined Behaviour in GNU C, and you shouldn't expect meaningful results from it.

You can use inline asm to copy `%rsp` to another register, and there might be some GNU C builtin functions to get the stack or frame pointer; I forget.  If you're going to do anything with the stack pointer, you should probably just write your whole function in asm.

---

#### It turns out you were just missing the `register` keyword.

Always check for compiler warnings, especially when doing "weird" stuff, which includes *anything* with the `asm` keyword.  Or any time you don't get the expected output.

gcc7.2 -O3 -Wall says:

```
5 : <source>:5:11: warning: ignoring asm-specifier for non-static local variable 'bp'
     void *bp asm("rbp");
           ^~
  ... format-string warnings you should fix...

6 : <source>:6:5: warning: 'bp' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     printf("Frame pointer %u\n", bp);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**If you write `register void *bp asm("rbp");` it appears to work, passing the register values to printf the way you were expecting.**

[gcc7.2 -O3 -Wall on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%0A++++register+void+*bp+asm(%22rbp%22)%3B%0A++++printf(%22Frame+pointer+%25p%5Cn%22,+bp)%3B%0A%0A++++register+void+*sp+asm(%22rsp%22)%3B%0A++++printf(%22Stack+pointer+%25p%5Cn%22,+sp)%3B%0A%0A++++char+c+%3D+!'A!'%3B%0A++++printf(%22Character+at+location+%25p%5Cn%22,+%26c)%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:41.078167115902964,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),header:(),k:26.80515301543561,l:'4',m:74.46592065106816,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:25.534079348931837,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:58.921832884097036,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), with the bugs fixed and using the `register` keyword for register asm locals.  Remember this isn't *supported*, but does happen to do what you want in gcc7.2 for x86-64.

```
main:
    push    rbp         # save the old rbp (but it *isn't* making a "stack frame" with mov rbp, rsp)
    mov     rsi, rbp    # copy rbp (caller's value) as 2nd arg to printf
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0   # format string
    xor     eax, eax
    sub     rsp, 16         # IDK why gcc allocates more stack space
    call    printf
    mov     rsi, rsp        # pass current rsp as 2nd arg to printf
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
    xor     eax, eax
    call    printf
    lea     rsi, [rsp+15]               # &c
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
    xor     eax, eax
    mov     BYTE PTR [rsp+15], 65
    call    printf
    add     rsp, 16
    xor     eax, eax
    pop     rbp                        # restore caller's RBP even though we didn't modify it
    ret
```

Probably using `rbp` as a register asm variable makes gcc act as if it was "used", thus saving & restoring.

If you want a stack frame, use `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.  (This is the default at -O0, [but nobody wants to read `gcc -O0` output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output).)